# How to store all the data coming from a modal and not only it's ID ANGULAR 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I'll give you an example of what I exactly want to say because I couldn't find a better way to ask the question.

I have these interfaces :

```
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { User } from "./user.model";

export interface Order{
  _id?: string;
  user: User;
  product: Product;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
}


export interface Product {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  images: string;
  stock: number;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  createdAt:Date
}

export interface User {
  _id:string,
  username:string,
  email:string,
  role:string,
  password:string,
  token:string
}
```

in the checkout component I have this function to create an order and store it :

```
createOrder(): void{
  this.cart.forEach((item)=>{
    this.order = {
      user: this.user,
      product: item.product, 
      price: item.product.price * item.number,
      quantity: item.number
    }

    this.orderService.post(this.order).subscribe(
      (res:Order) => {
        console.log('Order created');
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
  })
}
```

So everything is going okay the data is adedd successfully but It only store The PRODUCT ID and the USER ID not all the data of both of them.

I want to have the following:

```
{
  _id:1,
  user: {
    _id:2,
    username:'someone'
  },
  product: {
   _id: 1,
   name:'something',
   price: 99.99,
   stock: 244,
  },
  price: 201.00,
  quantity:2
}
```

but I only find:

```
 {
    _id:1,
    user:2,
    product:1,
    price: 201.00,
    quantity:2
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two sides of this issue: 1) you'll probably want to structure `this.order` differently if you want to send your intended structure with post, and 2) your `Order` interface will have to be different (to have the structure you hope to receive). This 2) might not be needed, but you'll have to share `User` and `Product` interfaces too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added the user and product interfaces but what do you mean by storing this.order differently ? Could you explain that

Comment: Can you share an example of `this.user` and `this.cart` from the `createOrder` method?

Comment: Thank you I found the solution using populate in the backend because  I use MongoDB for the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mongoDB, there's an operator called `populate` that uses the **id** (user_id, product_id, order_id) and return all/part of its related data (user, product, order) based on their **modals** in the backend and depending on what parameters you choose to get back.

if you calling for orders list, with use of this operator you get `user` as an object of all user related data. the same for `product`.

So I think you need to check with your backend team, I think every backend technology has its own **populate()** operator or equivalent to it.

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I needed.